# Fixed Position the top of a Div to the Bottom of Parent div

Tags: html, css, position, css-position

I have a interesting issue in terms of positioning a div.

I am using Relatively absolute positioning to position the child div b inside the parent div a. I know how to position them with their bottom edges aligned, using bottom:0px, but I need them to position so the top of B is aligned to the bottom of A, as shown in the diagram below.

Is there any way of doing this in CSS given that I can't be sure the height of B. My current CSS is below.

The Aim -

[image: Diagram]

HTML -

```
<div id="a">
     <div id="b"> </div>
</div>
```

CSS -

```
#a{
   position: relative;
}

#b{
   position: absolute;
   bottom:0px;
}
```

Comment: You say you don't know the height of b. Do you know the height of a?

Comment: You can do that with margins, BUT, if you want to align them outside of each other, why place b inside a in the first place? Wouldn't a parent container c around both be more suited to this task?

Comment: "but I need them to position so the top of B is aligned to the bottom of B" - do you mean: "... the top of B is aligned to the bottom of A".

Comment: Sorry, I should clear some things up. The html is being generated by Custom Post List Plugin for Wordpress so I don't have great control over the htmls structure.

Comment: Yeah, Top of B to Bottom of A. Fixed.

Comment: I don't know either the height of A or B. Margins wouldn't work because of this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you're after `top: 100%`: http://jsfiddle.net/ysafx/

```
#a {
    position: relative;
    outline: 1px solid red
}

#b {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-top: 5px;
    outline: 1px solid blue
}
```

Comment: bingo. An alternative solution I came up with a second ago is margin-top: 100%; top: 0px;

Answer (score -1):

If you don't know the height,

You must write the code like this:

CSS:

```
#a {
   position: relative;
   background: black;
   color: #fff;      
}

#b {
   position: relative;
   background: blue;
   color: #fff; 
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="a">
    // Your code inside a
</div>
<div id="b">
    // your code inside b
</div>
```

See the Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rathoreahsan/cKsVK/

Comment: In the question I specified that I don't know the height of B. In fact I can't be certain of the height of A either.

Comment: Yes I know, I mentioned in my answer that `b` depends on height of `a`. Without specified height we can't reposition a div inside a main div.

Comment: If you don't know the hieght then You must position the div `b` outside of the div `a` to achieve your goal.

Comment: Well then why did you provide this answer, if you knew it wouldn't work?